Problem with node_modules in nextjs project
i cloned a next project and then i run npm i , then when i did npm run dev to run the application ,
the app does not work and give me so much errors and issues.
my node and npm versions are compatible with my next version
i have node 20 npm 10 and next 14
i cloned a next project and then i run npm i , then when i did npm run dev to run the application ,
the app does not work and give me so much errors and issues,
on the terminal :
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\router-reducer\router-reducer.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\router-reducer\reducers\restore-reducer.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\router-reducer\router-reducer.js|app-pages-browser

[....]

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/is-plain-object.js
./node_modules/next/dist/lib/is-error.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/is-hydration-error.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/helpers/use-error-handler.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/lazy-dynamic/bailout-to-csr.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\lazy-dynamic\bailout-to-csr.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\bailout-to-client-rendering.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\lazy-dynamic\bailout-to-csr.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\on-recoverable-error.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/lazy-dynamic/bailout-to-csr.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/bailout-to-client-rendering.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/magic-identifier.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\magic-identifier.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\react-dev-overlay\internal\components\hot-linked-text\index.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\magic-identifier.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\react-dev-overlay\internal\components\hot-linked-text\index.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/magic-identifier.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/components/hot-linked-text/index.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/container/Errors.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/ReactDevOverlay.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/app/hot-reloader-client.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/page-path/ensure-leading-slash.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\page-path\ensure-leading-slash.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\app-paths.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\page-path\ensure-leading-slash.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\app-paths.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/page-path/ensure-leading-slash.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/app-paths.js
./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/interception-routes.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/reducers/has-interception-route-in-current-tree.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/action-queue.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\action-queue.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\use-reducer-with-devtools.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\action-queue.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\app-index.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/action-queue.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/use-reducer-with-devtools.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/add-path-prefix.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\add-path-prefix.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\add-base-path.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\add-path-prefix.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\add-base-path.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/add-path-prefix.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/add-base-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/app-paths.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\app-paths.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\server\future\helpers\interception-routes.js|app-pages-browser      
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\app-paths.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\server\future\helpers\interception-routes.js|app-pages-browser      

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/app-paths.js
./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/interception-routes.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/reducers/has-interception-route-in-current-tree.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-bot.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\is-bot.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\app-router.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\is-bot.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\components\app-router.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/is-bot.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/parse-path.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\parse-path.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\add-path-prefix.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\parse-path.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\add-path-prefix.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/parse-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/add-path-prefix.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/add-base-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/path-has-prefix.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\path-has-prefix.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\has-base-path.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\path-has-prefix.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\has-base-path.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/path-has-prefix.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/has-base-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js

./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/remove-trailing-slash.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\remove-trailing-slash.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\normalize-trailing-slash.js|app-pages-browser
* javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\remove-trailing-slash.js|app-pages-browser
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    javascript/auto|C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@next\react-refresh-utils\dist\loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-flight-client-module-loader.js!C:\Users\pc\Documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[16].oneOf[5].use[1]!C:\Users\pc\documents\mc\adanev-front\node_modules\next\dist\client\normalize-trailing-slash.js|app-pages-browser

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/utils/remove-trailing-slash.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/normalize-trailing-slash.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/add-base-path.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js`your text`
[......]

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js
./node_modules/date-fns/esm/sub/index.js
__barrel_optimize__?names=sub!=!./node_modules/date-fns/esm/index.js
./src/shared/_mock/_mock.ts
./src/shared/_mock/index.ts
./src/hooks/use-mocked-user.ts
./src/hooks/index.ts
./src/app/page.tsx
 GET /favicon.ico 200 in 3974ms



Give us the error logs from the top, not the bottom
